# how to pull data from view to file and attach to email

Tags: views, webforms, flags

I have a particular use case where I want to be able to convert an existing list of Flags into a file and attach this to an email sent to the admin and user.

I currently have a working Flags list set up. What I would like to do is to covert this view to a file and be able to email it to my user and myself (admin) on the forms submission.

I envision implementing this through 1) creating the Flag list 2) converting to file 3) emailing this as an attachment to an email through the webform.

I've found modules that deal with data export, but I need some guidance on how to implement this. I suspect I may have to build my own module, but I'm only starting to dive into how to do this. Any advice on where to jump off would be greatly appreciated.

I imagine this will take the following steps: 1) check that flag list is populated 2) if flag list is populated write it to file 3) upon form submit, email a copy to user/admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to use [Views PDF](https://drupal.org/project/views_pdf) module to output of views as PDF.
2. Use [Mime Mail](https://drupal.org/project/mimemail) module to send email with attachment.

Write own custom logic to action performed or any rules.

Custom function to send mail as attachment visit [here](http://rapiddg.com/blog-post/drupal-7-html-e-mail-pdf-attachments).

You may also check [this](http://rajanmayekar.com/blog/gererating-pdf-and-sending-it-email-attachment-drupal)